# Using SQL ORDER BY for complex criteria

Tags: order-by, database-agnostic

Let's say my relation is like so

[image]

and I wanted to sort by rank, but A's and B's first. So my relation will look like

[image]

At first I tried to just have two relations, where I order both of them by rank, then union the two relations, but they just end up getting jumbled together. I've also tried using cases, but I don't understand how it works. I kept getting errors about mixing characters with integers.

Edit: Forgot to mention that the first relation above is what I end up with after a somewhat complex number of views. For example, I created two views, one which only has A and B classes, then I ordered that by rank. Second view just C classes, ordered that by rank. Then I unioned them, but they just get mixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only need a `CASE` expression in the `ORDER BY`, to divide the rows into two groups, so the ones with class 'A' or 'B' are put in first group (`1`) and the all the others in the second (`2`):

```
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN class IN ('A', 'B') THEN 1 ELSE 2 END,
    rank ;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to give you one example of a way to do it, where I use CTEs, which are available in many databases, particularly PostgreSQL which I am most familiar with.

## CTEs and the `WITH` clause

[**CTEs**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/queries-with.html) allow you to form temporary, single-query table like structures, but since you can make CTEs rely on one-another in a single query, it provides a convenient and easy-to-understand way to make your query semi-procedural.

In your case, I would try

```
WITH AB_results AS(
  SELECT class, rank, 1 AS hidden_rank
  FROM my_relation
  WHERE class IN ('A','B')
),
Non_AB_results AS(
  SELECT class, rank, 2 AS hidden_rank
  FROM my_relation
  WHERE class NOT IN ('A','B')
)
SELECT COALESCE(AB_results.class,Non_AB_results.class), rank
FROM AB_results
FULL OUTER JOIN Non_AB_results
USING(hidden_rank,rank)
ORDER BY hidden_rank, rank;
```

I'll try to put together a SQLFiddle in a couple minutes here, just to make sure I didn't get some of my query wrong.  :P

EDIT: I did make a small error.  Trying to clean it up in an example as we speak.

EDIT 2:  The error is now corrected! Unfortunately, SQLFiddle is having a little trouble right now, but **[HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/8cb737)** is the link to the SQLFiddle for some testing.

*Please note* that I may not have solved this in the most elegant possible way, but it should solve your issues.